# Java: Pass by reference for mutable objects in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, pass-by-reference, mutable

In java I know that references are also passed by value. Is the only way to get this working is by returning prev? Are there other alternatives?

head is class variable

```
convertTreeToSortedDoublyLinkedList(root, null);
private void convertTreeToSortedDoublyLinkedList(Node node, Node prev) {
        if(node == null){
            return;
        }

        convertTreeToSortedDoublyLinkedList(node.left, prev);

        node.left = prev;
        if(prev != null) {
            prev.right = node;          
        } else {
            head = node;            
        }

          Node right = node.right;
          head.left = node;
          node.right = head;
          prev = node;

        convertTreeToSortedDoublyLinkedList(right, prev);   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to have an object with the references to node and priv inside it, modify that object from the called method and the calling method will see the change.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

- You return the new reference as you suggested
- You wrap the reference in another reference so you can update the inner reference without a problem.

A simple solution would be an array:

```
Node[] ref = new Node[1] {prev};
ref[0] = //update here
```

I think option one would be better here because the Ref-Ref or the array would just clutter the method

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I use option 1 to return the reference should that be a class variable. In my code should prev be a class variable?